# How comes this "if" passes but for real it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, oop, js.class

Good day, first I would like to tell that I am not proud to post a whole source code. I couldn't isolate the problem in a smaller chunk.

Here is a snapshot of the file:

```
getRoomById : function( areaId, roomId ) {
    if ( this.hAreas.get( areaId ) !== null && this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] !== undefined )
    {
        //I can get here...
        //alert( uneval( this.hAreas.get( areaId ) ) );
        // returns: ({'000001':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000001", Informations:{Name:"Room 1"}}, '000002':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000002", Informations:{Name:"Room 2"}}, '000003':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000003", Informations:{Name:"Room 3"}}})

        //alert( roomId );
        // returns: 000003

        return this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ];
        // returns: undefined
    }
},
```

and the whole file is there: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWCu/2/

The problem: I have a method which tests the arguments against a `JS.Hash` containing an object. That `if` hopefully returns true but once inside, I can't get (either alert or return) the object inside that `JS.Hash` (an undefined is returned).

Thank you! your help is greatly appreciated. I would also appreciate tips to avoid such errors.

Edit: here is the whole codes. Sorry It's really big. It's just starting to get complex and I couldn't (for now) isolate the problems to a smaller piece of codes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            JSCLASS_PATH = 'http://www.poc.ca/cybrix/src';
            function appendConsole( input ) {
                document.getElementById( "console" ).innerHTML += input + "<br />";
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.poc.ca/cybrix/src/loader-browser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            JS.require('JS.Hash', 'JS.Observable', function() {
                var AreaLists = {
                    "000001" : { "Name" : "Test Area", "Loaded" : false },
                };

                var World = new JS.Class({
                    hAreas : new JS.Hash([]),

                    getAreas : function( areaId ) {
                        if ( ! this.hAreas.get( areaId ) && AreaLists[ areaId ] !== undefined )
                        {
                            //TODO: Load from external sources

                            this.hAreas.put( areaId, {
                                "000001" : new Room( areaId, "000001", { "Name" : "Room 1" } ),
                                "000002" : new Room( areaId, "000002", { "Name" : "Room 2" } ),
                                "000003" : new Room( areaId, "000003", { "Name" : "Room 3" } ),
                            });

                            AreaLists[ areaId ].Loaded = true;

                            appendConsole( "Areas #" + areaId + " : " + AreaLists[ areaId ].Name + " Created" );
                        }

                        return this.hAreas.get( areaId );
                    },
                    getRoomById : function( areaId, roomId ) {
                        if ( this.hAreas.get( areaId ) !== null && this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] !== undefined )
                        {
                            //I can get here...
                            //alert( uneval( this.hAreas.get( areaId ) ) );
                            // returns: ({'000001':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000001", Informations:{Name:"Room 1"}}, '000002':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000002", Informations:{Name:"Room 2"}}, '000003':{areaId:"000001", roomId:"000003", Informations:{Name:"Room 3"}}})

                            //alert( roomId );
                            // returns: 000003

                            return this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ];
                            // returns: undefined
                        }
                    },
                    reloadAreas : function( areaId ) {
                        //Triggered by Tick only if there is no players
                    },

                    addCharacter : function( areaId, roomId, character ) {
                        if ( this.hAreas.get( areaId ) && this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] )
                        {
                            this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ].addCharacter( character );
                        }
                    },
                    removeCharacter : function( areaId, roomId, character ) {
                        return this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ].removeCharacter( character );
                    }
                });

                var Room = new JS.Class({
                    hDoors : new JS.Hash([]),
                    hExits : new JS.Hash([]),
                    hBodies : new JS.Hash([]),
                    hObjects : new JS.Hash([]),

                    initialize : function( areaId, roomId, Informations ) {
                        this.areaId = areaId;
                        this.roomId = roomId;
                        this.Informations = Informations;

                        //TODO: Load from external sources
                        if ( areaId == "000001" && roomId == "000003" )
                        {
                            this.hObjects.put("000001", new Objects("000001", { "Name" : "A table", "Type" : 0 }) );
                            this.hObjects.put("000002", new Objects("000002", { "Name" : "A water fountain", "Type" : 1 }) );
                        }

                        appendConsole( "Room: #" + this.areaId + "-" + this.roomId + " : " + this.Informations.Name + " Created" );
                    },

                    addCharacter : function( character ) {
                        this.hBodies.put( character.characterId , character );

                        character.onArriveRoom( this );

                        if ( ! character.Informations.Stealth )
                        {
                            //TODO: Broadcast Informations to others

                            appendConsole( character.Informations.Name + " has arrived to " + this.Informations.Name );
                        }
                    },
                    removeCharacter : function( character ) {
                        var characterId = ( typeof character == "object" ) ? character.characterId : character,
                            currentCharacter = this.hBodies.remove( characterId );

                        character.onLeaveRoom( this );

                        if ( currentCharacter !== null )
                        {
                            //TODO: Broadcast Informations to others

                            appendConsole( character.Informations.Name + " has left " + this.Informations.Name );

                            return currentCharacter;
                        }

                        return undefined;
                    },

                    onArrive : function() {

                    },

                    onLeave : function() {

                    },

                    getObjects : function( objectId, hash ) {
                        if ( this.hObjects.get( objectId ) )
                        {
                            var currentObjects = this.hObjects.get( objectId );

                            if ( hash )
                            {
                                return new JS.Hash([
                                    currentObjects.objectId, currentObjects 
                                ]);
                            }

                            return currentObjects;
                        }

                        return this.hObjects;
                    },

                    toString : function( characterId ) {

                    }
                });

                var Objects = new JS.Class({
                    objectsTypes : {
                        0 : "lies",
                        1 : "stands"
                    },

                    initialize : function( objectId, Informations ) {
                        this.objectId = objectId;
                        this.Informations = Informations;

                        appendConsole( "Object: #" + this.objectId + " : " + this.Informations.Name + " Created" );
                    },

                    toString : function() {
                        return this.Informations.Name + " " + this.objectsTypes[ this.Informations.Type ] + " here.";
                    }
                });

                var Character = new JS.Class({
                    Pet : undefined,

                    initialize : function( characterId, Informations ) {
                        this.characterId = characterId;
                        this.Informations = Informations;
                        this.areaId = this.Informations.Zone.split("-")[ 0 ];
                        this.roomId = this.Informations.Zone.split("-")[ 1 ];

                        if ( this.Informations.Pet !== undefined )
                        {
                            //TODO: Load from external sources

                            if ( this.Informations.Pet === "000001" )
                            {
                                this.Pet = new Pet( "000001", { "Name" : "Molten Panther", "Zone" : this.areaId + "-" + this.roomId, "Stealth" : false } );

                                World.addCharacter( this.Pet.getArea() , this.Pet.getRoom() , this.Pet );

                                var petRoom = World.getRoomById( this.Pet.getArea() , this.Pet.getRoom() );

                                alert( petRoom ); // = undefined ????
                            }
                        }

                        appendConsole( "Character: #" + this.characterId + " : " + this.Informations.Name + " Created" );
                    },

                    onArriveRoom : function ( currentRoom ) {

                    },
                    onLeaveRoom : function( currentRoom ) {

                    },

                    onArrive : function() {

                    },
                    onLeave : function() {

                    },

                    getRoom : function() {
                        return this.roomId + "";
                    },
                    getArea : function() {
                        return this.areaId + "";
                    },
                    getInformations : function() {
                        return this.Informations;
                    },
                    hasPet : function() {
                        return ( typeof this.Pet == "object" );
                    },
                    getPet : function() {
                        return this.Pet;
                    },

                    equals : function( character ) {
                        return ( character instanceof this.klass ) && character.Informations.Name === this.Informations.Name;
                    }
                });

                var Pet = new JS.Class( Character, {

                    initialize : function( characterId, Informations ) {
                        this.callSuper();

                        appendConsole( "Pet: " + this.Informations.Name + " Created" );
                    }
                });

                //Tests
                var World = new World();
                var AreaOne = World.getAreas( "000001" );

                var Cybrix = new Character( "000001", { "Name" : "Cybrix", "Zone" : "000001-000003", "Stealth" : false, "Pet" : "000001" } );

                if ( World.getAreas( Cybrix.getArea() ) )
                {
                    World.addCharacter( Cybrix.getArea() , Cybrix.getRoom() , Cybrix );

                    //Cybrix = World.removeCharacter( Cybrix.getArea() , Cybrix.getRoom() , Cybrix );
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div id="console" style="display: block; background-color: #000; height: 100%; color: #FFF; font-family: Lucida Console;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And yet, despite it being massive, please post the *entire* question here on StackOverflow. Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Oh: And do keep trying to create a (much) smaller, self-contained example. :-)

Comment: @T.J.: Cannot agree more with the second comment ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you guys, and I'm sorry, I'll try to isolate the problem some more. About the small chunk of codes, I believe I've provided enough informations on the problem : how could the `if` passes when once you return the value it is undefined ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the objects? What does `alert(JSON.stringify(this.hAreas.get(areaId)));` result in?

Comment: @T.J.: Yay! Also, as an addendum on #1, the OP will be LESS likely to get responses. That... mouse... click... is... sooo... HARD...

Comment: @Paul V - I suggest Firebug of Chrome console. :)

Comment: I've created a much smaller version, two objects and 4 methods in total and the problem is fixed. What would be my mistake? Did I loop through objects references and they got destroyed ?

Comment: @Paul V, here is the returned value using `JSON.stringify` : `{"000001":{"areaId":"000001","roomId":"000001","Informations":{"Name":"Room 1"}},"000002":{"areaId":"000001","roomId":"000002","Informations":{"Name":"Room 2"}},"000003":{"areaId":"000001","roomId":"000003","Informations":{"Name":"Room 3"}}}`

Comment: @Cybrix - I've posted an answer below which I think resolves the issue. World.getRoomById returns a ROOM object. You've overrode the Room class' toString() method and are not returning anything so it returns undefined by default. That's why when alerting(petRoom) you get undefined.

Comment: @Jared - hah! Of course! `alert(JSON.stringify)` is easier to describe though :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around with your example on jsfiddle and I'm running into some rather odd behavior. In your `Character` class' `initialization` method you're calling the `World.getRoomById()` method in question and assigning it to a variable called `petRoom`.

As your code stands, when you `alert(petRoom)` you do get `undefined`. However, if you `alert(petRoom.roomId)` you get `000003` as intended so my guess is it's not really returning a *true* undefined. If you log petRoom to chrome's console it classifies it as a constructor and not an object. I'm not really sure what's going on there, but I thought it'd give some extra direction. I'll keep playing.....

**UPDATE:** The issue is that you're overriding the `Room` class' `toString()` method and not returning anything. By default, alerting something cast it to a string using the object's `toString()` method and because you've overridden that and aren't returning a value you get undefined.

```
var Room = new JS.class({
        ...
        snip
        ....
        toString: function(characterId) {

        }
});
```

Comment: Hmm indeed. I can also access petRoom as if it was the object itself. I'm confused right now...

Comment: You just need to remove the overriden toString() method in your Room class or have it return something. World.getRoomById is returning your object fine, it's not returning undefined. You're just seeing undefined when you ALERT because alert uses the object's toString() method, which you've overriden.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question in the comments

> how could the `if` passes when once you return the value it is undefined

You're using the comparison `this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] !== undefined`. What that will do is test that the value on the left isn't *strictly equal* to that specific `undefined` instance. If you're dealing with multiple windows/frames, it's possible to have different `undefined` instances (because each window has its own `undefined`). If that sounds really weird, it's because it is.

To guard against that, you usually see that comparison written as:

```
if (typeof this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] !== "undefined")
```

...which tests that the *type* of the operand is "undefined" (note the quotes), which is reliable cross-window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
typeof this.hAreas.get( areaId )[ roomId ] !== "undefined"
```

Comment: `typeof` always returns a string :)